# Rules governing narrowing of double to int

Tags: java

Please note I am NOT looking for code to cast or narrow a double to int.

As per [JLS - $ 5.1.3 Narrowing Primitive Conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3)

> A narrowing conversion of a signed integer to an integral type T
>   simply discards all but the n lowest order bits, where n is the number
>   of bits used to represent type T.

So, when I try to narrow a 260 (binary representation as `100000100`) to a byte then result is 4 because the lowest 8 bits is `00000100` which is a decimal 4 OR a long value 4294967296L (binary representation `100000000000000000000000000000000`) to a byte then result is 0.

Now, why I want to know the rule for narrowing rule from double to int, byte etc. is when I narrow a `double` value `4294967296.0` then result is `2147483647` but when I narrow a long `4294967296L` value then result is `0`.

I have understood the long narrowing to int, byte etc. (discards all but the n lowest order bits) but I want to know what is going under the hoods in case of double narrowing.

Comment: The answer is a few lines after the one you quoted: _A narrowing conversion of a floating-point number to an integral type T takes two steps: [...]_

Comment: I did read it, but I really couldn't get my answer from it. I could understand that it would be done from 1.b but couldn't understand how. I would be much obliged if you could please throw light.

Comment: I think it would somewhere end up on understanding double to float narrowing rule, governed by the IEEE 754 rounding.

Comment: @hagrawal: "The value must be too large (a positive value of large magnitude or positive infinity), and the result of the first step is the largest representable value of type int or long."....

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Thank you for your inputs. If I go by the algorithm mentioned there then this is true "if the floating-point number is not an infinity, the floating-point value is rounded to an integer value V, rounding toward zero using IEEE 754 round-toward-zero mode" because my number is 4294967296.0 which is not inifinity . Which means that now there would be rounding toward zero using IEEE 754 round-toward-zero mode. No?

Comment: Yes.  But your number is already an integer value.

Comment: It is floating point number (double) - 4294967296.0 .. Right ?? And it is not infinity so should be rounded, no ??

Comment: Yes it's a double, but it has an integer value (compare to say 4294967296.3).

Comment: Yes sir, every double (or a decimal number) will have an integer part. So, does it mean that as per "IEEE 754 round-toward-zero mode" rule, 4294967296.0 will be rounded to 4294967296. And then as per step2 of the algorithm, it would be narrowed as per §5.1.3). But then why result is not 0 but 2147483647 ?

Comment: Round toward 0 means to largest integer less than 4294967296.0 which should be 4294967296

Comment: Because "integer **value**" is not the same as saying that the **type** has been converted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have understood the long narrowing to int, byte etc. (discards all but the n lowest order bits) but I want to know what is going under the hoods in case of double narrowing.
>
> ... I want to understand the why and how part.

1. The JLS ([JLS 5.1.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3)) specifies what the result is.  A simplified version (for `int`) is:

   - a NaN becomes zero
   - an Inf becomes "max-int" or "min-int"
   - otherwise:

     - round towards zero to get a mathematical integer
     - if the rounded number is too big for an `int`, the result becomes "min-int" or "max-int"
2. "How" is implementation specific. For examples of how it *could be* implemented, look at the Hotspot source code (OpenJDK version) or get the JIT compiler to dump some native code for you to look at.  (I imagine that the native code maps uses a single instruction to do the actual conversion .... but I haven't checked.)
3. "Why" is unknowable ... unless you can ask one of the original Java designers / spec authors.  A plausible explanation is a combination of:

   - it is easy to understand
   - it is consistent with C / C++,
   - it can be implemented efficiently on common hardware platforms, and
   - it is better than (hypothetical) alternatives that the designers considered.

   (For example, throwing an exception for NaN, Inf, out-of-range would be inconsistent with other primitive conversions, and could be more expensive to implement.)

Comment: Thank you for your inputs. Ohh Ok. I got it now. I think I got confused because of write up in JLS (or probably there is confusion). Please correct me if I my understanding is wrong - As per algo steps there, 3rd bullet of #1 "Otherwise, one of the following two cases must be true: " will be executed when floating point is an infinity (which means a FALSE for 2nd bullet for #) as well as after rounding off in #2 if results cannot be represented as long or int.

Comment: If you could let me know your inputs, then we could close this. Please let me know if above comment is not clear to you.

Comment: I have closed it. But once you have little time, please do let me know your inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Result is Integer.MAX_VALUE when converting a double to an integer, and the value exceeds the range of an integer.  Integer.MAX_VALUE is 2^31 - 1.

Comment: How and why is the question.

Comment: The spec doesn't say why, it just says that is the result.

Comment: Yes, I agree but I want to understand the why and how part.

Comment: It says on the page: """The value must be too large (a positive value of large magnitude or positive infinity), and the result of the first step is the largest representable value of type int or long. """

Comment: I am not sure if that is the case here, I have commented the same.

Comment: 4294967296.0 > 2147483647 which is Integer.MAX_VALUE.  As for why, since it guarantees not to generate an exception, then MAX_VALUE is the best it can do.

Comment: I agree with your first part but partly agree with second part, but there is more to why thing ..

Comment: I have closed this question. Thanks for your inputs.

Answer (score 1):

When you start with the double value 4294967296.0, it is greater than the greatest long value which is 2147483647 so the following rule is applied (from the page you cited) : *The value must be too large (a positive value of large magnitude or positive infinity), and the result of the first step is the largest representable value of type int or long* and you get 0x7FFFFFF = 2147483647

But when you try to convert 4294967296L = 0x100000000, you start from an integral type, so the rule is : *A narrowing conversion of a signed integer to an integral type T simply discards all but the n lowest order bits* so if n is less than 32 (8 bytes) you just get a 0.

Comment: Thank you for your inputs. If I go by the algorithm mentioned there then this is true "if the floating-point number is not an infinity, the floating-point value is rounded to an integer value V, rounding toward zero using IEEE 754 round-toward-zero mode" because my number is 4294967296.0 which is not inifinity . Which means that now there would be rounding toward zero using IEEE 754 round-toward-zero mode. No?

Comment: Long.MAX_VALUE =  9223372036854775807