# What guarantees does the C++ standard give for narrowing conversion from double to int?

Tags: c++, casting, standards, narrowing

What guarantees does the C++ standard give for narrowing conversion from double to int types?
Is it the same as Java as explained at [Q31328190](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31328190/rules-governing-narrowing-of-double-to-int):

Comment: While it's not the specification, [this reference site](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) does a good job of following the specifications. It of course has a section about [floating to integral conversions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast#Floating.E2.80.93integral_conversions).

Comment: Thanks for reminder about this site. However, if I search "Implicit" it comes up with no results. How do you find something if you don't know where it is  and the search fails to find pages that exist!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not the same as in Java. If the mathematical result of "truncate the fractional part" cannot be represented by the target type, the behaviour is undefined.

From 4.9 [conv.fpint]/1 ("Floating-integral conversions"):

> A prvalue of a floating point type can be converted to a prvalue of an integer type. The conversion truncates; that is, the fractional part is discarded. The behavior is undefined if the truncated value cannot be represented in the destination type.

Comment: This just means the integer type should be large enough to accommodate the truncated value. Basically, you want the float to be between the `std::numeric_limits<int>::min()` and `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()`. For everything else, there are unit tests :D